# Have a youtube video stop after popopping up as an overlay

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

Here is some code where when you click on a link/image, an embedded youtube video is revealed as an overlay, similar to a lightbox effect.

When I have one video set up, the video will stop playing when I click on the 'x' to closer the popup/overlay.

If I add more videos, the video continues to play in the background.  The overlay is hidden but the audio still runs.

Can you help me find out how to stop the video? I need a total of 6 videos on a page.

**HTML:**

```
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a onclick="startoverlay()" href="#" title="Watch video" class="flex-item box-link bg-lightgrey fg-darkgrey">
                <div class="tiled-image" id="img0">
                    <div class="tiled-overlay">
                        <h3 class="sm-title hblack text-uppercase"><strong class="fg-white"> <span class="fa fa-play" aria-label="Play"></span> </strong></h3> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tiled-body">
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a onclick="startoverlay2()" href="#" title="Watch video" class="flex-item box-link bg-lightgrey fg-darkgrey">
                <div class="tiled-image" id="img0">
                    <div class="tiled-overlay">
                        <h3 class="sm-title hblack text-uppercase"><strong class="fg-white"> <span class="fa fa-play" aria-label="Play"></span> </strong></h3> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tiled-body">
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

**Overlays:**

```
<!-- VIDEO ONE OVERLAY-->
<div id="overlay" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-video-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-right">
                <button type="button" class="close" id="close-button" onclick="startoverlay()" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">×</span> </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-video">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe id="video" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6HOlHZfqzxk?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- VIDEO TWO OVERLAY-->
<div id="overlay2" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-video-label">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-right">
                <button type="button" class="close" id="close-button" onclick="startoverlay2()" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">×</span> </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-video">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe id="video" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o1aVMcrb4aE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modal-backdrop" class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

For the second part of the script I have duplicated the overlay code and called it startoverlay2 - I am not sure if that is correct.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">a
    var player;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        var pauseButton = document.getElementById('close-button');
        pauseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            player.pauseVideo();
        });
    }
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/player_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    </script>
    <!--  /* overlays */ -->

    <!-- /*    OVERLAY 1     */ -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function startoverlay() {
        el = document.getElementById("overlay");
        el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
        els = document.getElementById("modal-backdrop");
        els.style.display = (els.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    }
    </script>

    <!-- /*    OVERLAY 2     */ -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function startoverlay2() {
        el = document.getElementById("overlay2");
        el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
        els = document.getElementById("modal-backdrop");
        els.style.display = (els.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    }

</script>
```

I do wonder if I need to do something to the pauseButton var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, it looks like you need to tell the video to stop playing. As you're using the `iframe` version of the YouTube player, we can do this by replacing it's `src` tag with the same value.

```
// get the video's surrounding overlay
el = document.getElementById("overlay");

// hide the overlay, or show it if it's already hidden
el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";

// Restart the video (paused)
var videoIFrame = el.querySelector('iframe');
srcUrl = videoIFrame.getAttribute('src');    
videoIFrame.setAttribute('src', srcUrl);
```

This causes the video to be reloaded, taking you back to the (paused) start state, ready for the modal to be opened again.

If you want to pause the video in its current place, you'll want to consider using the API rather than the iframe option.

It's a bit outside the scope of the question, but there's also some refactoring you could do to reduce the code repetition, for example pulling the JS into a single 'hide' function:

```
function stopAndHide(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";

    // Restart the video (paused)
    var videoIFrame = element.querySelector('iframe');
    srcUrl = videoIFrame.getAttribute('src');    
    videoIFrame.setAttribute('src', srcUrl);

    els = document.getElementById("modal-backdrop");
    els.style.display = "none";
}
```

and then calling it from the HTML as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="close" onclick="stopAndHide(this)" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">×</span> </button>
```